# Работа веб-приложения с базой данных

Tags: mysql, ajax, веб-программирование

Привет! На странице сайта есть планировщик задач. Задачи можно добавлять, присваивать им различные приоритеты, сроки и т.п. Всё работает на JS.
Каким образом передавать измененные данные базу?
вариант 1. При каждом внесенном изменении пользователя формировать запрос в базу и вносить эти изменения.
вариант 2. По окончании работы с приложением пользователь нажимает "сохранить" и в базу передается текущее состояние задач.
Других вариантов в голову не пришло. Как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от архитектуры задачи.
Проще всего нарисовать кнопочку "Сохранить", которую делать активной при изменении каких-либо положений. И по клике на неё отправлять запрос.
Вариант 1 слишком неправильный, ибо любое изменение, даже случайное, будет записано.
Вариант 2 лучше первого, правда не намного.

Comment: А чем ваш вариант принципиально отличается от моего второго?

Comment: Ну между "закончить работу в приложением, при выходе сохранить" и "просмотреть одну страницу, её сохранить" есть разница.